# Counter implementation using NsTimer in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, counter

I have surfed on a bunch of `resources` from the internet but still couldn't get any idea of what I'm trying to implement.

- I would like to record user preferences by detecting how much time they have stayed in each information `pages`.
- In order to make this question simpler, that says I have a entrance page with `5 different theme pages` which represent different information.
- I would like to know which page is the page that user most interesting.
- What I wish to do is to put a counter in each theme pages and calculate how much time they stay in that page (the `counter` should be able to pause for reentrance), and then when I press a button on the entrance page, an alert will tell me which page is the page that user spent most of time on it.

I hope this make sense!

Does anyone have any experience on this? I would be most appreciative if anyone can provide some codes and examples for me.

Comment: you should use some analytic service. link http://www.google.co.in/analytics/mobile/

Answer (score 2):

ViewController A:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    //create iVar of NSInteger *seconds
    seconds = 0;

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(increaseTimeCount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}

- (void)increaseTimeCount {
    seconds++;
}

- (void)dealloc {
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // you can add to array too , if you want and get average of all values later
   [defaults setInteger:seconds forKey: NSStringFromClass(self)];
}
```

now in Entrance View ..
get the time as

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger *secondsInView = [defaults integerForKey:NSStringFromClass(View1ClassName)];
```

Comment: Thanks for the replied. I need timer to be able to pause for reenter the page.Could you tell me how to do that??

Comment: you can assign second value from NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I'd like to draw your attention to the Cocoa/CF documentation (which is always a great first port of call). The Apple docs have a section at the top of each reference article called "Companion Guides", which lists guides for the topic being documented (if any exist). For example, with NSTimer, [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) lists two companion guides:

- [Timer Programming Topics for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html)
- [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html)

For your situation, the Timer Programming Topics article is likely to be the most useful, whilst threading topics are related but not the most directly related to the class being documented. If you take a look at the Timer Programming Topics article, it's divided into two parts:

- Timers
- Using Timers

For articles that take this format, there is often an overview of the class and what it's used for, and then some sample code on how to use it, in this case in the "Using Timers" section. There are sections on "Creating and Scheduling a Timer", "Stopping a Timer" and "Memory Management".There are a couple of ways of using a timer. From the article, creating a scheduled, non-repeating timer can be done something like this:

**1) scheduled timer & using selector**

```
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                  target: self
                  selector:@selector(onTick:)
                  userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
```

- if you set repeats to NO, the timer will wait 2 seconds before
  running the selector and after that it will stop;
- if repeat: YES, the timer will start immediatelly and will repeat
  calling the selector every 2 seconds;
- to stop the timer you call the timer's -invalidate method: [t
  invalidate]; As a side note, instead of using a timer that doesn't
  repeat and calls the selector after a specified interval, you could
  use a simple statement like this:

  [self performSelector:@selector(onTick:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

this will have the same effect as the sample code above; but if you want to call the selector every nth time, you use the timer with repeats:YES;

**2) self-scheduled timer**

```
NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60.0];
NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
                          interval: 1
                          target: self
                          selector:@selector(onTick:)
                          userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[t release];
```

- this will create a timer that will start itself on a custom date
  specified by you (in this case, after a minute), and repeats itself
  every one second

**3) unscheduled timer & using invocation**

```
 NSMethodSignature *sgn = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(onTick:)];
 NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: sgn];
 [inv setTarget: self];
 [inv setSelector:@selector(onTick:)];

 NSTimer *t = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                  invocation:inv 
                  repeats:YES];
```

and after that, you start the timer manually whenever you need like this:

```
NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer: t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

And as a note, onTick: method looks like this:

```
-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
   //do smth
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this simple method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   count = 0; // Declare int * count as global variable;
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerAction
{
    [self custom_method:count++]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a different route. If you take the time since reference date, when the user enters the page:

```
NSTimeINterval time = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
```

then do the same when they leave the page and compare them.

```
timeOnPage = time - time2;
```

This is much more efficient than firing a timer on another thread unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the replied but I need counter to be able to pause for re-entrance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use NSTimers for this at all.

Store the date/time when the user starts viewing, and calculate the time difference when they stop viewing using simple time arithmetic.

Comment: Actually, I'm a beginner. So far timer is the only route that I can imagine. Could you give me some example of how to implement the idea by using your way??

Comment: @geminiCoder has suggested the same thing, with some sample code. [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] is the key. Store that value at the beginning, check the difference at the end. If you want to handle pausing, you can keep a sum of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly As Dave Wood says You should use date and time for starting and ending viewing that screen and calculate the difference and then save it to any integer variable.Using NSTimer will make the performance effect in your app and make the compiler busy while incrementing the count.